# Magento 2.3 upgrade no longer reading my catalog_product_view.xml

Tags: php, magento

Since upgrading my Magento 2.3 from 2.9.2, Magento no longer is reading my catalog_product_view.xml

My catalog_product_view.xml is located at app/code/{Company}/ProductTheming/view/frontend/layout/

Here is my XML:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name="video.tab" class="{Company}\ProductTheming\Block\Product\View\Video" template="{Company}_ProductTheming::catalog/product/view/video.phtml" />
        <block name="features.tab" class="{Company}\ProductTheming\Block\Product\View\Features" template="{Company}_ProductTheming::catalog/product/view/features.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="attributes_model" xsi:type="object">{Company}\ProductTheming\ViewModel\Product\View\Attributes</argument>
        </arguments>
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{Company}_ProductTheming::catalog/product/view/section_wrapper.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

No error is given, it just is defaulting back to the stock Magento. However my theme is working.

Answer (score 0):

hi you custom theme your theme default.xml of magento 2.3, should be in folder like this:

app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml.

this will update your xml.  for better further detailed structure please refer to

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=quick_search&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=XML%20instruction#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex